# How to use Eiffel functions?

Tags: function, eiffel

So I'm just starting to learn Eiffel. One of the first exercises in the book I'm using says to make a function that does base^exp without using ^. I've copied my code below.

```
class
    APPLICATION

inherit
    ARGUMENTS

create
    make

feature {NONE} -- Initialization

    make
            -- Run application.
        do
            create power(2;3)
            printf("2 to the power of 3 is " + answer)
        end

    power(base : REAL; exp : INTEGER) : REAL
        -- computers base raised to the bower of exp without using ^
        local
            remain : INTEGER
        do
            remain := exp
            if remain = 0 then
                result := 1
            else
                from
                until
                    remain = 0
                loop
                    result := result * result
                    remain := remain -1
                end
            end
        end
end
```

How do I use this? Do I need it on the same level as `feature{NONE}`'s `make`? I know how I'm calling it is wrong, and I can't find anything in the chapter I just read, or online on how to pass parameters into it or how to use it's results.

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues with the original code:

1. `create` is used to create an object, but you are not going to create anything, but to get a result of a computation of the function `power` by calling it. Therefore the keyword `create` is not needed.
2. You are using an entity `answer` to report the result of evaluation on a screen. However it is not declared anywhere. I believe the proper place would be a local variable declaration section.
3. The entity `answer` is not initialized to the result of the function `power`. This is usually done by an assignment instruction.
4. Feature arguments are separated by a comma, not by a semicolon.
5. From the original code it's unclear what is the type of the variable `answer`. Assuming it matches the type of the function `power`, before adding it to a string, it needs to be converted to a string. This is done by calling the feature `out`.
6. The standard feature for printing a string to a console is `print`, not `printf`.

Combining the critical points above, we get

```
make
        -- Run application.
    local
        answer: REAL
    do
        answer := power(2, 3)
        print ("2 to the power of 3 is " + answer.out)
    end
```

After that the code can be compiled. Now less critical points:

7. It is a good style to put features to a dedicated feature clauses, so I would add a line like `feature -- Basic operations` before the feature `power`.
8. The implementation of the feature `power` has at least two problems. I'm not going to detail them here, but would give two hints instead:

   - by default numeric `Result` is initialized to `0`, this needs to be taken into account for operations that use it without first assigning any other value
   - even though an argument `base` is passed to the function `power` it remains unused in the original version of the code